# .NET MAUI COMET: Scrollview doesnt appear

Tags: c#, .net, maui

found something strange in Maui Comet
In the following code, the scrollview and everything inside doesnt show, does anyone know why?

```
Body = () => new VStack()
        {
            Header(),
            Bon(),
            Footer()

        };

        Comet.View Header()
        {
            return new HStack()
            {
                new Text("Header!")
            }
            .Background(Colors.Red)
            .Padding(0)
            .Margin(0)
            .Color(Colors.Black)
            .Frame(height: 150, width: 1900);
        }

        Comet.View Bon()
        {
            return new Comet.ScrollView()
            {
                    new Text("Bon!")
            }
            .Background(Colors.Green)
            .Padding(0)
            .Margin(0)
            .Color(Colors.Black)
            .Frame(height: 670, width: 1900)
            ;
        }

        Comet.View Footer()
        {
            return new HStack()
            {
                new Text("Footer!")
            }
            .Background(Colors.Blue)
            .Padding(0)
            .Margin(0)
            .Color(Colors.Black)
            .Frame(height: 150, width: 1900);
        }
```

Here is a picture of the screen i am getting now:

[image]

UPDATE

```
something as simple as this wont work:
 Body = () => new Comet.Grid(
                columns: new object[] { "*" },
                rows: new object[] { "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*" })
        {
//Scrollview example
                new Comet.ScrollView {
                    new VStack {
                        new Text("Title"),
                        new Text("Description").FontSize(12).Color(Colors.Grey),
                    }.FillHorizontal().Cell(row:1, column: 0, rowSpan: 4)
                },
        };
```

If I remove the grid it works, but I want to keep the grid

Comment: Is your grid rendering on top of your scrollview?  Set a background color to grid.